# bizarre C statement

Tags: c, c99

```
void test(int x[static 10]);  

int main()  
{  
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};  
    test(a);  
    return 0;  
}  

void test(int x[static 10])  
{  
    printf("%d",x[9]);  
}
```

I was looking for bizarre C statements. I found this one, But could not understand what is the use of `static 10` in that statement. Is it same as `int x[10]`?

Another thing, you can use `volatile` also, in place of `static` e.g `int x[volatile 10]`
Anybody knows what is the use of this kinda declaration?

PS: Compiled using GCC 4.6.3,

Answer (score 5):

It's a hint for the compiler telling that the `x` pointer parameter points to the first element of an array of at least `10` elements.

For example:

```
test(NULL);  // undefined behavior
```

Comment: is this valid C++? how useful is it in the optimization (ie like inline or better?) - just trying to get more info, thanks

Comment: yeah, but program run without error, warning even if provided arguments are NOT at least 10

Comment: @ChrisCM see my example, passing a `NULL` argument is undefined behavior.

Comment: hm.. @ouah as in, compile time check? how does it differ from passing NULL into (int x[]) ?

Comment: @AK4749 even assuming `test` function body is empty, `test(NULL);` is UB.

Comment: @AK4749 regarding C++, to my knowledge this feature does not exist in C++

Comment: got it - so no compile time safety, but provides runtime optimization possibility at the cost of broadening the scope of UB? Thanks for the clarifications

Comment: what about `int x[volatile]` guys ?

Comment: @AkashShende `void foo(int p[volatile 10]);` is equivalent to `void foo(volatile int *p);`